# Azure: Where do I find my role's logs when using Remote Desktop?

Tags: azure, remote-desktop

When I run my worker role locally, I can open the Windows Azure Compute Emulator application and look at the standard output and error of my worker process.

When I remote desktop into my Azure instance, I don't know where to get that same information. Where do I find standard output and error?

Comment: Are you using System.Diagnostics.Trace to write message in your worker role?

Comment: No, I'm running a Worker Role with a non-.NET `ProgramEntryPoint`. However, I can see that that is not clear from my question---I'll open a new question to address that.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827388/) if you are using `ProgramEntryPoint` to run a non-.NET app in an Azure Worker Role.

Comment: When you are using .net then Azure Diagnostics is a great to have it. I will respond to your other question over there..

Answer (score 3):

If you want to see your standard output and error of your worker process in an actual deployment then you will need to do some additional configuration. This data must be stored in a persistent storage.

First step is to enable Diagnostics in the configuration window of your `WorkerRole`. Here a storage account must be specified.

The next step is to add additional code to the `OnStart()` method of your `WorkerRole`. Here you can not only configure the standard output and error, but also you can listen to windows events and diagnostic information as provided in the following code example.

```
public override bool OnStart()
{
    DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration diagConfig = 
        DiagnosticMonitor.GetDefaultInitialConfiguration();

    // Windows event logs
    diagConfig.WindowsEventLog.DataSources.Add("System!*");
    diagConfig.WindowsEventLog.DataSources.Add("Application!*");
    diagConfig.WindowsEventLog.ScheduledTransferLogLevelFilter = LogLevel.Error;
    diagConfig.WindowsEventLog.ScheduledTransferPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

    // Azure application logs
    diagConfig.Logs.ScheduledTransferLogLevelFilter = LogLevel.Verbose;
    diagConfig.Logs.ScheduledTransferPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

    // Performance counters
    diagConfig.PerformanceCounters.DataSources.Add(
        new PerformanceCounterConfiguration()
    {
        SampleRate = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
        CounterSpecifier = @"\Processor(*)\% Processor Time"
    });
    diagConfig.PerformanceCounters.ScheduledTransferPeriod = 
        TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    DiagnosticMonitor.Start(
        "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString", diagConfig);
    return base.OnStart();
}
```

After these settings your diagnostic data will be visible in the configured Azure Table storage. You can easily write tools to visualize your data here, but there are also some commercial tools that have built in functionality for this. For example
[Cerebrata Diagnostics Manager](http://cerebrata.com/Products/AzureDiagnosticsManager/Download.aspx).

If for some reason you don't want to use Azure Storage for storing log files you can implement a custom trace listener that may write logs anywhere else. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647545.aspx) is a description about how to do that. You may simply open a http port and transfer them to your own server.

Answer (score 0):

Trace message are not stored anywhere in Window Azure instead if you configure Azure Diagnostics properly those message are sent to Windows Azure Table Storage (WADLogsTable Table) from there you can get them.

If you want to know how to enable Azure Diagnostics for Traces visit the link below and look for **Windows Azure Diagnostics Demonstration** code sample:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh411529.aspx

You can learn details about Azure Diagnostics [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff714589.aspx).